# Python Selenium - List all the text of the same class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all the "title" of *the class* "lien-jv topic-title", my code is running without any error. But the print function is showing nothing, the code just ends without showing any result.

What I want to get is all the topics title in the page. In the example below, it would be:
"***Pourquoi les gens déprécient le COSTARD/COSTUME de nos jours ?***"

```
<a class="lien-jv topic-title" href="/forums/42-51-68065824-1-0-1-0-pourquoi-les-gens-deprecient-le-costard-costume-de-nos-jours.htm" title="Pourquoi les gens déprécient le COSTARD/COSTUME de nos jours ?">Pourquoi les gens déprécient le COSTARD/COSTUME de nos jours ?
                            </a>
```

Website = https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-51-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-18-25-ans.htm

```
import os
import webbrowser  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

os.system('cls')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-51-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-18-25-ans.htm')
time.sleep(2)

list_topic_main=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("lien-jv topic-title")
for x in list_topic_main:
    print(x.title)

browser.close()

os.system('pause')
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `class name` not `css selector`:

```
list_topic_main = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("lien-jv topic-title")
```

And i believe you meant `text` not `title`:

```
print(x.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a accept cookie pop up, that you need to click first.

Also I am using below `CSS` and then looking for title attribute using `.get_attribute()`

**Code :**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
browser .maximize_window()
#browser .implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

browser .get("https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-51-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-18-25-ans.htm")
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='Didomi.setUserAgreeToAll();']"))).click()
except:
    pass

for title in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.lien-jv.topic-title"):
    print(title.get_attribute('title'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
Règles du forum.
QUAND avez vous ENTENDU parler du GRAND REMPLACEMENT pour la PREMIÈRE FOIS
"Je vais PARTIR au CANADA / DANEMARK / NORVÈGE" :rire:
A quoi jouer après The Last of Us 2 ?
DAVOS prévoit un BLACKOUT MONDIAL en OCTOBRE
Je sors avec une 9/10 et vous ?
Zevent 2021 | 29, 30, 31 Octobre 2021
Pascal OP : je m'en fous de l'avis de ma famille je suis toujours
[OFFICIEL] No Nut November 2021
ALLER sur VINTED, voir un CUL moulé DANS un JEAN..
PASCAL OP se BRANLE pendant qu'il CONDUIT sur l'autoroute
[VIDEO] le CAS des MEUFS qui S'EMBROUILLENT pour RIEN ( CAS D'ETUDES )
CNEWS, Renaud camus sur le GR : « J’encourage les Français à croire ce qu’ils voient »
Mort du père du Tiramisu
C'est quoi la LOGIQUE du CHANGEMENT D'HEURE ?
Je reprends contact avec une pute du lycée sur DISCORD
[FIC] "Tu l'as encore jamais fait Célestin ?? "
Asselineau : "Madame gros caca xDDD"
CÉLESTIN à Hoywood bordel
Notez moi MECHAMMENT /10
Ahii quel mot est né la même que VOUS ?
(FILLE) Ce 6/10 PETIT de TAILLE qui fait de la DRAGUE de RUE
"Le rap cette sous culture pour débile"
ma lapine s’ENDORT aux chiottes
DAVOS prévoit un BLACKOUT MONDIAL en OCTOBRE
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *title* attribute i.e. *`Pourquoi les gens déprécient le COSTARD/COSTUME de nos jours ?`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.lien-jv.topic-title[href*='pourquoi-les-gens-deprecient']").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='lien-jv topic-title' and contains(@href, 'pourquoi-les-gens-deprecient')]").get_attribute("value"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.lien-jv.topic-title[href*='pourquoi-les-gens-deprecient']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='lien-jv topic-title' and contains(@href, 'pourquoi-les-gens-deprecient')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)